# I am trying to display data from an external API, how can I fix the issue in my code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

This is the error message I am getting

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'drinkList.drinks[0]')

How can I fix the error so that I can use the app to fetch data from the external api?

This is my drink.js code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Drinks from "./Drinks";

function Home() {
  const [drinkName, setDrinkName]= useState([]);
  const [drinkList, setDrinkList] = useState([]);
  const drinksURL = `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${drinkName}`;

  const handleChangeDrink= e => {
    setDrinkName(e.target.value);
  }

  const getDrink = () => {
    axios
      .get(drinksURL)
      .then(function (response) {
        setDrinkList(response.data);
        console.log(drinksURL);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.warn(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <main className="App">
      <section className="drinks-section">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name of drink (e.g. margarita)"
          onChange={handleChangeDrink}
        />
        <button onClick={getDrink}>Get a Drink Recipe</button>
        <Drinks drinkList={drinkList} />
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

This is my Drink.js code:

```js
import React from "react";

function Drinks({ drinkList }) {
  if (!drinkList) return <></>;
  return (
    <section className="drinkCard">
      <h1>{drinkList.drinks[0].strDrink}</h1>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Drinks;
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems here...

1. `drinkName` is initialised as an array but it appears to be expecting a string
2. `drinkList` is initialised as an array but the data from the API is an object. You may want to assign the `drinks` array from the response instead
3. `drinksUrl` is never updated
4. An empty array is still *truthy*

Some easy fixes

```js
const [drinkName, setDrinkName]= useState(null) // initialise as null
const [drinkList, setDrinkList] = useState([])

// don't include the "s" parameter here
const drinksURL = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php"

const getDrink = () => {
  // pass drinkName as a param
  axios.get(drinksURL, {
    params: { s: drinkName }
  }).then(res => {
    // note that we're extracting `drinks`
    setDrinkList(res.data.drinks)
  }).catch(console.warn)
}
```

and in `Drink.js`

```
function Drinks({ drinkList }) {
  // check the array length
  return drinkList.length && (
    <section className="drinkCard">
      <h1>{drinkList[0].strDrink}</h1>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Comment: still an error occurs

Comment: the error is located on the drinklist.length

Comment: @georgiobejjani all fixed now.